# Where to import handsontable css files in react project

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

I've started using handsontable for my react project. I was going through the handsontable documentation for react (https://handsontable.com/docs/7.2.1/frameworks-wrapper-for-react-installation.html). I did the installation process, but I got stuck in one place. In the basic usage of the documentation they have mentioned that we have to import the CSS files.

Mentioned in the docs.

```
@import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css';
```

When I run the react project, the CSS is not getting applied.

[image]

I don't know where to import CSS files in my react project. Please anyone help

Comment: Try doing just in your root `index.js` file. Make sure your webpack config support importing of CSS using an appropriate loader (or whatever building tool you're using).

Comment: I used import "handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"; in the index.js file and it worked.